# How to return data to client as I get it from an external api?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, api

I have an app for which I have a backend in node. Suppose there is an API endpoint (/get_menu) to get all the menus.
When app calls /get_menu, I call external APIs of different restaurants and when all of them return their menu I am sending it to app. I am using Promise.all for that.

As some restaurants are taking a lot of time so I want to return the data back to app as I keep getting data from restaurants APIs. For example, if two of them return their menu instantly then I return those two back to app and after that as I keep getting data for other APIs I keep sending it to app.

What are some good ways to do that with single API endpoint i.e. /get_menu ?

Comment: Probably don't use `Promise.all` ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of solutions for this

1. To give you a literal answer for what you ask, you can use some
   implementation of socket like socket.io to send data to your client
   anytime you want.
2. The second option would be to persist the menu of the restaurants in
   a database and serve the user from there. In the background,
   periodically update your database with a cron. It's not really
   advisable to keep your user waiting until all your menu API's are
   resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use redis based queue mechanism for this. You can push each API as a job in this queue.

There is a very good redis based queue npm package [Bull](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bull). There are events to notified when a job processing is finised. You can then send data back to to the app once job is finised.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a web worker  on the client -side javascript that uses a UUID (unique ID to request that the server fetches the list of menus)

the server then will create a database entry assigning the various remote api requests each a unique id as well. Then, node.js sends a list of the request ids back to the client immediately and is rendered.  A background task to fetch the menus is run separately, each time a result comes in, its stored in a Database.  The client web worker will periodically request the list of UUIDs that it needs, and the server will respond with the ones that have responded. the data is deleted once sent to the client and the client renders the results and renoves that uuid from its list of requests to retrieve data for..

its essentially a crude unreliable result queue that can run safely as long as your server can keep up with all the requests.

Also see 'Event Sources' on the internet.

A more modern version of this involves a similar implmentation using websockets and a websocket server if your host is very reliable.